# Can't apt-get upgrade or install, dkpg --configure -a hangs at "Setting up open-iscsi"

Tags: apt, 18.04, dpkg, iscsi

I've been unable to upgrade or install packages for a few months. Whenever I use an apt-get command, it tells me dpkg was interrupted. When I run the command it suggests, it hangs at "Setting up open-iscsi"

```
{ 15:29 ☀ } ~ ➭ sudo apt-get install aria2
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
{ 15:29 ☀ } ~ ➭ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-5) ...
Setting up python3-apt (1.6.3) ...
Setting up curl (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.9) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
done
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.5) ...
update-initramfs: Not updating initramfs.
Setting up open-iscsi (2.0.874-5ubuntu2.4) ...
```

If you hit ctrl+C at this point, the process continues with an error at the end:

```
^Cdpkg: error processing package open-iscsi (--configure):
 installed open-iscsi package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
Setting up qemu-utils (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.9) ...
Setting up perl (5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up python3-problem-report (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.5) ...
Setting up libisccfg160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up libvirt-daemon (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.6) ...
Setting up openssh-sftp-server (1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up sosreport (3.6-1ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up unattended-upgrades (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.7) ...
Setting up nginx-core (1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up python3-gdbm:amd64 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.96.24.32.6) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libvirt-clients (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.6) ...
Setting up python3-lib2to3 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
Setting up libgs9:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.3) ...
Setting up python2.7-dev (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up python3-distutils (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
Setting up git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up networkd-dispatcher (1.7-0ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up qemu-system-common (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.9) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.96.24.32.6) ...
Setting up samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up libvirt-daemon-system (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.6) ...
virtlockd.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up libvirt-daemon dnsmasq configuration.
Setting up libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.6) ...
Setting up libirs160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up python-samba (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up libbind9-160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up ghostscript (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.3) ...
Setting up python3-apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.5) ...
Setting up nginx (1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up qemu-system-x86 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.9) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.5) ...
apport-autoreport.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up libvirt-bin (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.6) ...
Setting up bind9-host (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up qemu-kvm (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.9) ...
Setting up dnsutils (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:18.04.29) ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:18.04.11.8) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:18.04.29) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:18.04.11.8) ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.1.4) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.5) ...
update-initramfs: Not updating initramfs.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 open-iscsi
```

I'm running 18.04.1 with a RAID setup. The system is operating normally otherwise.

Comment: You could start by debugging open-iscsi's post install script, which should be located in /var/lib/dpkg/info/open-iscsi.postinst. Have a look at it, and perhaps run it manually. It could well be a matter of changing a folder or the restart command. Alternatively, you could uncomment this postinstall script and run the upgrade manually. Just make sure afterwards, that open-iscsi is working just fine.